# How to use Xilinx's IP solutions based RTL design for simulation using Cocotb? Can Xilinx IP be verified using Icarus?

Tags: vivado, cocotb

I have a design that has Xilinx FIFO IP. I am trying to verify the design using COCOTB based testbench. How can I include a Xilinx based IP for simulation using COCOTB? The simulation tool that I am using is Icarus.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have Icarus set up so that you can compile your design without cocotb?
If so, take a look at one of the Makefiles under cocotb's `examples/*/tests/` directory, copy one of them and fill out the variables so that it fits your design (see https://cocotb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building.html#make-variables to see what they mean).
Then, `make SIM=icarus` should already do something useful.